# Transformation of daily dates into fortnight in R

Tags: r

I would like to know is there a way to transform dates like this
     "2016-01-8" in "20160101q" which means the first half of January 2016 or
     "20160127" in "20160102q" which means the second half of January 2016 for example and thank you in advance?

Comment: How do you define first half and second half of a month?

Comment: the first half : from 1 to 15 and the seconde half after 15

Answer (score 0):

you can try with mutate and paste0, first you decompose the date in day, month and year. then create a variable that says if we are in the first or second half of the month, then paste the sting text of month, year and the variable containing "01q" or "02q" depending on the period

```
date<- c("2016-01-8",
"2016-01-27")
id <- c(1,2)
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, date)) 

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
x = x %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(date), funs(year, month, day))
x$half <- "01q"
x$half[day>15] <- "02q"
paste0(x$year,x$month,x$half)
```

Comment: Not working in February, where day number 15 should be in `02q`.

Comment: @Wimpel according to Abdel_El  "the second half is after 15". in case I can add a condition for February and specify: x$half[day>14 & month=="February"] <- "02q"

Comment: instead of "lubridate::mday(date) / lubridate::days_in_month(date) > 0.5" you can put "lubridate::mday(date) > 15" . in this way it is considered 02q for any day more than 15

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution makeing use of `data.table` and the `lubridate`-packages.

It uses the `lubridate::days_in_month()`-function, to determine the number of days in the month of the date. This is necessairey, since February has (normally) 28 days, so day 15 of February --> 02q. But January has 31 days, so day 15 of January --> 01q.

The logic for calculating the q-periode is:

`If day_number / number_of_days_in_month > 0.5 --> q periode = 02q, 
    else q_period --> 01q.`

Then a `paste0` command is used to crete the text for in de `q_date`-column. `sprintf()` is used to add leading zero for single-digit monthnumbers.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
#sample data
data <- data.table( date = as.Date( c("2019-12-30", "2020-01-15", "2020-02-15", "2020-02-14") ) )
# date
# 1: 2019-12-30
# 2: 2020-01-15
# 3: 2020-02-15
# 4: 2020-02-14

#if the day / #days of month > 0.5, date is in q2, else q1
data[ lubridate::mday(date) / lubridate::days_in_month(date) > 0.5, 
      q_date := paste0( lubridate::year(date), sprintf( "%02d", lubridate::month(date) ), "02q" ) ]
data[ is.na( q_date ), 
      q_date := paste0( lubridate::year(date), sprintf( "%02d", lubridate::month(date) ), "01q" ) ]

#          date    q_date
# 1: 2019-12-30 20191202q
# 2: 2020-01-15 20200101q
# 3: 2020-02-15 20200202q
# 4: 2020-02-14 20200201q
```

Comment: it work for me i juste put ifelse condition : q_date<-ifelse(lubridate::mday(date) / lubridate::days_in_month(date) > 0.5, paste0( lubridate::year(date), sprintf( "%02d", lubridate::month(date) ), "02q" ),paste0( lubridate::year(date), sprintf( "%02d", lubridate::month(date) ), "01q" ) ]